# Grab random value the remove from array

Tags: php

I am wanting to use a form confirmation to display a single use code and then discard the code so it wont be used again. So far this is what I have:

```
    $codes = array(
    '810',
    '0190',
    '1924',
    '481',
    '2941',
    '8777',
    '092',
    '432',
    '984',
    '172',
    '8483'
);

$rand_code = array_rand($codes);
$code_gen = $codes[$rand_code];

return $confirmation = 'Here is your code:' . $code_gen;
```

This shows me a random code each time I submit the form so it works perfect. I need to actually store that code and not use it again. What would be my best solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a database instead of hardcoded array

Comment: So you need to use some data later on? and don't wish to override it? Have you looked into sessions, cookies, databases, text files, or any other form of storage that may exist?

Comment: Why not just use `md5()`? And if you want it to be shorter than shorten the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle to get a random one, then pop it out, bam.

```
shuffle($codes);

while($code_gen = array_pop($codes)){
    return $confirmation = 'Here is your code:' . $code_gen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prepend the datetime to the ticketnumber then you are guaranteed that your number is not used again without needing to store it. (unless we have time travellers).

e.g. 110912032634 = ticket 1 and 110912032785 = ticket 2

If you mean by "later on" in the session, use sessions, etc...

If you mean by "later on" : after a month to collect data, then store it in a database